# Macbook Pro will not sync with iPhone time

Tags: macbook-pro, data-synchronization, time

MBP 13" 2017 - Catalina - 10.15

The time is annoyingly off by ~2 minutes 55 seconds. I've confirmed with other iPhone users and the time on our phones are the same, it's just that **MY** Macbook time is slow.

This is a computer for work so it's irritating to get notifications for each meeting at different times on MBP and iPhone. Interestingly, when I receive messages on Slack, the timestamp is *ahead* of my system time.

Time Zone is correct both manually and when I select the "set time zone automatically" option.

When I use the ”Set date and time automatically” the time doesn't actually change. The time uses "Apple Americas (time.apple.com)

Querying the time server directly results with the following info:

[image]

I then went to time.is and see the following discrepancy:

[image]

Comment: In an attempt to reduce latency, your iPhone may be fetching the time from the nearest cell towers rather than via the internet. This is especially true if your iPhone is not connected to WiFi. In any case, the discrepancy should not be more than a few seconds. — Can you confirm that, on your Mac, in Date & Time preferences, "Set date and time automatically" is checked and an Apple time server is selected, e.g. `time.apple.com`?

Comment: You can query the time server directly via the terminal with e.g. `sntp -d time.apple.com` to see what time the clock should be set to. Unfortunately, you cannot easily do these checks on your iPhone, nor can you choose or enforce the use of a specific time server.

Comment: @JivanPal I've updated the question with the information you've provided. Do you see any issues in the time query?

Comment: Nope, the system time is in sync with the time reported by the server (14:54 Central Standard Time), so the issue must be with your phone, as I previously described. There's not much you can really do except to try and force the iPhone to get the time over the internet. You can try this by connecting to WiFi and removing the SIM card; or turning on Airplane mode, then turning on WiFi. Then restart the device with this configuration and see if it re-syncs the time. Even if this works, I wouldn't be surprised if it goes back out of sync later, though.

Comment: @JivanPal that would mean that the time should change on the phone depending on if I am on the same wifi as the MBP or using cell, correct? I don't think this is it because the other iphone users and I have the same time on our phones. Their phones also match their MBPs. My MBP seems to be the one with the problem

Comment: It's not about being connected specifically to the *same* WiFi network, it's about being connected solely to the internet so that the phone asks an NTP server directly for the time, rather than asking the nearest cell phone tower, whose answer may be received late due to latency or otherwise be inaccurate.

Comment: I found an iOS app called [Emerald Time](https://apps.apple.com/app/emerald-time/id290384375) that will allow you to see the time as determined by NTP on your iPhone. If this differs from the time that's actually set on the device, it's surely due to your iPhone deriving time from a cell tower, or another issue (e.g. NTP service not running properly)

Comment: Thanks again for the responses @JivanPal but I want to confirm there are no issues with the iPhone time, as everyone else in the office with iPhones have the same time. The issue is with my MBP, which is several minutes slower than everyone else's iPhones and Macs. In fact, messages on Slack are match up with iPhone time but are timestamped several minutes ahead than the system time on my MBP.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Visit https://time.is/ on your MacBook — is any discrepancy reported? "The difference from Time.is was ..."

Comment: @JivanPal yes, there is a discrepancy of 2 minutes 55 seconds as of this posting. Updated original post with new screenshot

Comment: The time should correct itself the instant you check the "Set date and time automatically" checkbox (may need to unlock first).  Does Console.app reveal anything?

Comment: @RobT, I apologise, the figure `+138.201493` in the Terminal screenshot shows that you are 138 seconds slow. To sync your system time, run `sudo sntp -Ssd time.apple.com`. It is strange that checking the box in Date & Time preferences does not automatically sync the time for you, though.

Comment: @JivanPal thank you, that command updated the system time and now everything is synced. However, it does not explain why it happened.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, if you have something specific to look for I could check, as I am not familiar with Console

Comment: @JivanPal I did time.is and queried the time server and as of 8:52am the system is 40.2 seconds behind. Any other ideas how to permanently fix this?

Comment: @RobT, you can check whether `timed` is running: `sudo launchctl list | grep com.apple.timed` should output something like `X Y com.apple.timed`, where `X` is the process ID, or `-` if the process is not running. If it's not running, that'd explain why your time is not being kept in sync. In that case, perhaps there is something wrong with the copy of `timed` installed on your system, or whatever is trying to invoke it on boot or when "Set time automatically" is toggled.

Comment: @RobT, barring that, I suppose you could set up a cron job to run `sntp` every 15 minutes or so. As it turns out, cron files don't exist anymore in macOS, so you have to do it with a `launchd` script: you can create a file `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.example.ntpfix.plist` [with these contents](https://gist.github.com/jivanpal/f227fd2137ebfd9c9be616d1f73ff825), then restart your Mac. If that doesn't work for whatever reason, I'd personally be inclined to just reinstall macOS.